# bolt and nut to remove toilet seat underneath

Tags: bathroom, toilet

I have to replace toilet seat in small space and not familiar with this tightening screw. I tried using pliers to pull it down but obviously need to remove the nut first. Any advice what tool to use to remove this?

[image]

Comment: I've not seen that type of attachment but if I had to guess, I'd say use the pliers to pull out the horizontal cylinder which seems to be attached to the two prongs. I expect that that would release the squarish ring.

Comment: Haven't seen this one before either, and unfortunately your photo is quite fuzzy. Is the threaded part of the rod above or below the ring?

Comment: let me try that, thank you @DoxyLover

Comment: yep quite difficult to take photo because of placement of this screw. the threaded part  is also below @MiG

Comment: Hope @DoxyLover's suggestion works. It's difficult to make out distances and available space on the photo, so I'm not sure if it's possible to use a wrench on that ring.

Comment: I had the same attachment, and I since I couldn't figure it out I used brute force - the nut did come of eventually when I applied force with the pliers, and the thing was even still in a usable state afterwards (I still replaced it with a more conventional attachment).

Comment: Are you sure there's not a way to attack this from above... like a screw head at the top... maybe under a plastic cover?

Comment: That looks a lot like a kind of "molly bolt" which is intended to be screwed & unscrewed from the top, as if the nut on the bottom is inaccessible. You probably won't be able to turn the nut as there's not enough space under there - you'll have to attack it from the top.

Comment: Grip the end of the bolt with pliers and turn it counter clockwise, you will be able to shuffle it a few times until it is loose enough for the nut to clear the nut holder

Comment: Sure is a tough one. Thanks for the suggestions guys. I will try suggestions but this does seem like unique fitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection seems to be a lot like this: https://www.guillens.com/buy/product/0061761000/450265

It looks as though the toilet seat pulls off, just held with O-rings and it exposes a space for a spanner to counter-clockwise turn the bolt out.

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I have. Issue is I can't hold the top part since the toilet seat covering it. Will try holding it and see if I can turn it somehow.

Comment: I think it is required to remove the seat. Guessing the original install method would be to bolt on the bolts to the toilet bowl and then press the seat on afterwards, probably clicking into grooves inside the seat holes.

Comment: That is correct Chris. I finally got it off, just had to use my superpowers and inspiration from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKq0DCUAduI